# Pasar una consulta linq C# de un botón a un clase para ejecutarla y llenar una grilla en un formulario

Tags: c#, windows-forms, linq, linq-to-sql

Tengo un botón con este código:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = db.Empleado
    .Where( x => x.id > 0)
    .OrderBy( x => x.nombre)
    .Select(y => new
    {
    y.nombre,
    y.apellido
    }
    ).ToList();
```

Tengo una carpeta data donde están los códigos de la clase Empleado para incluir, modificar, etc. porque me gusta reutilizar código..

Me gustaría crear un método en mi clase Empleado para agregar ese código (lo cual no se como debo hacerlo):

```
public void MostrarGrilla()
{
    var consulta = db.Empleado
                .Where( x => x.id > 0)
                .OrderBy( x => x.nombre)
                .Select(y => new
                {
                    y.nombre,
                    y.apellido
                }
                ).ToList();
}
```

Para desde el formulario escribir:

`dataGridView2.DataSource = Empleado.MostrarGrilla();`

He intentado varias cosas pero nada.. y es solo cuando utilizo el Select con el NEW.. pueden ayudarme por favor... El desarrollo es en Windows Form..

Comment: Hola, podrías decirme si la respuesta dada te fue útil

Comment: Buenas noches disculpe que responda tal tarde, todo me funciono ok según lo que me explicaste.. de verdad muchas gracias...

Comment: Hola, por favor si la respuesta te fue util te agradeceria que la marcaras como aceptada. Para marcar la respuesta como aceptada debes dar clic en el checkMark que sale al lado de la respuesta que te di

Comment: Estoy tratado pero no veo ese checkmark solo 3 cuadros, activo, mas antiguo y votos.. exactamente donde esta amigo...porfa

Comment: A la izquierda de la respuesta que te doy hay dos triángulos con un cero en el medio de ellos, si das clic en el triángulo con el piquito hacia arriba das un voto positivo, si das clic en el otro un voto negativo, en esa zona abajo de los triángulos te debe salir el checkmark, te agradecería que  dieras click en el checkmark y si lo consideras también dieras un voto positivo, gracias

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126193/japv entra aqui y avisame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en que estás construyendo un **objeto anónimo** que tiene 2 propiedades, nombre y apellidos, y al ser anónimo no hay un tipo definido para el, por lo que no puedes devolverlo   en una función.

Para solucionar esto debes aplicar el **patrón de diseño** **DTO(Data Transfer Object/Objeto de transferencia de datos)**

Los **DTO** son un patrón muy efectivo para transmitir información entre un cliente y un servidor, pues permite crear estructuras de datos independientes de nuestro modelo de datos, lo que nos permite crear cuantas “vistas” sean necesarias de un conjunto de tablas u orígenes de datos. Además, nos permite controlar el formato, nombre y tipos de datos con los que transmitimos los datos para ajustarnos a un determinado requerimiento. Finalmente, si por alguna razón, el modelo de datos cambió (y con ello las entidades) el cliente no se afectará, pues seguirá recibiendo el mismo DTO.

Por tanto creamos una clase con la estructura que resolvería tu problema:

```
public class Persona
{
   public string Nombre{ get; set; }
   public string Apellido{ get; set; }
}
```

Como ves esta clase tiene la estructura de dos campos **string** que es lo que devolvetrias en tu consulta **Linq**.

Entonces la consulta quedaría así:

```
public List<Persona> MostrarGrilla()
{
    List<Persona> consulta = (from e in db.Empleado
                              where e.id > 0
                              orderby e.nombre
                              select new Persona
                              {
                                 Nombre = e.nombre,
                                 Apellido = e.apellido
                              }).ToList()
```

Ahora tu consulta **Linq**, devolvería una lista, donde cada elemento de la lista es de tipo **Persona**, y esta consulta sería lo que devolviera tu función.

Otra forma de hacerlo es usando la **palabra reservada** **dynamic**, pero tienes que ser muy cuidadoso con su uso ya que los posibles errores no se detectan en tiempo de compilación sino en tiempo de ejecución, y esto conlleva que te vas a demorar bastante en encontrar el posible error. Investiga más en Internet sobre su uso, pero no abuses de ella.

Comment: Excelente me sirvio gracias