# DTO vs Entity - Es correcto usar una entity para construir un objeto?

Tags: c#, model, patron-dto

Contexto:

Estuve leyendo en distintos foros que el DTO (data transfer object) es útil para mostrar o devolver la información que necesitemos expresada a través de un objeto DTO que contenga parte o todos los atributos que tenga una determinada entity.
La duda es si a la hora de construir un objeto es necesario usar un objeto DTO con los mismos atributos que una entity solamente para este propósito? Ejemplo:

Tenemos una entity:

```
public Casa{
  private List<Habitaciones> habitaciones;
  private String domicilio;
}
```

Tenemos un DTO:

```
public CasaDTO{
  private List<Habitaciones> habitaciones;
  private String domicilio;
}
```

En este ejemplo solamente cambiamos el nombre de la clase, de esta manera se puede construir el objeto utilizando ambos modelos y no habría diferencia alguna. Entonces: De que me sirve tener una entity, si el DTO ya puede construir la casa? o viceversa.

Siguiendo con el mismo ejemplo, en el caso si tuviéramos que mostrar el perímetro de la casa, el cual es un dato calculado por lo que no estoy seguro si sería correcto agregar un atributo en la clase CasaDTO que sea `private double perimetro;`, aunque en caso de agregarlo, por lo menos ahí comprendo que exista una diferencia entre un DTO y un entity, ya que los modelos compartirían algunos datos pero habría al menos un atributo distinto, y podríamos usar al DTO para mostrar o devolver la información del perímetro de la casa.

Siguiendo en esta línea, desde mi entendimiento, para que tenga sentido crear un modelo Casa, lo usaría para construir una Casa y usaría CasaDTO para mostrar la casa con el perímetro, de otra manera no encuentro el porque crear una entity Casa tenga sentido; A su vez habiendo visto el código de distintas personas veo que muchas veces los modelos entities y los DTO's suelen tener los mismos atributos, me gustaría entender el porque de esto, cual sería el camino correcto a seguir acorde a las buenas practicas y en que qué casos o para qué sería útil una entity que tenga los mismos atributos que una clase DTO.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Si, es correcto.**

En .net por ejemplo tienes:

- Tienes `public` y `private`
- Variables y propiedades `{get;set;}`
- Atributos como `[NotMapped]` y `[NonSerialized]`

Con todas estas herramientas (y otras) tienes el suficiente control para configurar tus clases, de manera tal que puedas tener una clase con más o menos propiedades según lo requieras.

Es decir **tu clase no tiene por qué ser un reflejo exacto ni de la tabla de la base de datos, ni del objeto que necesitas transferir**. Y es por esto, que me atrevo a decir que en muchos casos las clases DTO no son necesarias.

Y además toda esta "configuración" sucede dentro de la misma clase, lo que brinda un orden, sabes donde tienes que ir a revisar antes cualquier cambio. No así con los DTO; llega alguien nuevo al proyecto y no sabe dónde revisar, porque no existe un acoplamiento formal del framework entre la clase y el DTO, solo existen, en el mejor los casos, nomenclaturas que tu equipo ha decidido usar, como poner el sufijo DTO a cada clase o tener una carpeta DTO

**¿Qué pasa si es necesario devolver un objeto totalmente distinto?**

Pues en ese caso creas esa clase y punto, tienes un caso particular donde tu objeto a transferir es lo suficientemente distinto a tu modelo como para crear esa clase. Pero no por crear un par de clases, vas a decir "a bueno, como estoy usando DTO y tengo que hacer lo mismo para las otras 100 clases"

---

Tu ejemplo de `Casa` y `CasaDTO`, es un buen ejemplo de lo que **NO** debe hacerse, tener 2 clases que son exactamente lo mismo atenta contra otro paradigma superior que es la orientación a objeto. Y en la práctica es una mala idea, ahora tienes 2 clases que mantener, 2 clases que actualizar ante cualquier cambio, y tu código ahora hará conversiones que hacen más difícil la depuración y ahora existe un enredo para seguir el hilo lógico del sistema; e imagina esto con una base de datos de 100 tablas, ahora tienes 200 clases.

La solución a esto ha sido utilizar mapeadores (como Automapper), grandísima mala idea, otra "cosa" que aprender a configurar, otra cosa que puede fallar y nuevamente agrega dificultades a la depuración. Es que francamente no tiene sentido alguno. Y nuevamente en el caso que lo tenga, creas esa clase "especial" y la mapeas a mano

---

**¿De dónde nacen las opiniones contrarias a lo que señalo?**

Me parece a un mal entendimiento del patrón. Hay que entender de donde nace el  DTO, quien lo crea y cuando lo postula.

El patrón se le atribuye a Martin Fowler a principio de los 2000, este tipo es un referente en arquitecturas y patrones (un CAPO con mayúsculas), pero con un enfoque predominante en JAVA.

Y esto último es muy importante, C# se parece a JAVA pero no son lo mismo. Y ahí es donde está el problema de muchos patrones que provienen de un pensamiento y una lógica de JAVA que se han querido migrar a C#, en muchos casos no es necesario, C# (.net para ser  más exacto) tiene sus formas de hacer las cosas sus paradigmas que vienen por default, y muy pocas veces hay necesidad de agregar capas adicionales que solo generan una telaraña.

La fecha de creación también es importante, porque Entity Framework y .net han cambiado mucho en los últimos años. Por ejemplo, antes existía un problema con las `Id` (las PK de las tablas), tu decías quiero una ID del tipo `int` autoincrementable, pero pasaba que al crear hacer binding en una vista de un
-CRUD de creación- surgía el problema de que en ese momento la ID era null, entonces ese `int` ahora tenías que transfórmalos a nuleable, pero en la base de datos es NO nulleable, lo que obligaba a crear una clase intermedia como lo puede ser un DTO, una clase con `int id` y otra con `int? id`. Bueno, esto ya no pasa.

Y en palabras del mismo Martin Fowler

Traducción:

> Un caso en el que es útil usar algo como un DTO **es cuando tienes un
> desajuste significativo** entre el modelo en su presentación capa y el
> modelo de dominio subyacente

[Enlace](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html)

El mismo dice que "un caso útil", lo cual implícitamente da a lugar a la existencias de casos inútiles, y esto lo recalco porque hay quienes usan el DTO a ciegas siempre. Luego continua y dice "**cuando tienes un desajuste significativo**", lo cual no sucede en tu caso de ejemplo, tu clases Casa y CasaDTO son las mismas.

**¿Estás diciendo que nunca hay que utilizarlas?**

Tampoco me voy al otro extremo, hay caso útiles y hay otros imprescindibles. En mi experiencia son necesarias cuando desarrollas el software sobre una base de datos grande, que alimenta a muchos otros software. Entonces el modelo de negocio de tu software no se ve reflejado en esa base datos (un `Data Warehouse` puede ser un ejemplo). Aquí te vez obligado en generar tus entidades de negocio a partir de mezclar tablas, calcular datos, seleccionar campos, etc. **Pero aquí no duplicas las clases, la clase DTO y la de Entity Framework serán distintas**

El caso totalmente contrario, es cuando empiezas un software de cero con su propia base de datos y además usas `code first`, en este caso se me hace difícil pensar el uso de DTO

---

Un pensamiento final y personal: Es mejor tener sentido común que conocer los 1000 patrones de diseño. A ti el sentido común te alertó que no puede ser útil duplicar las clases, por mucho que el paradigma lo señale.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, la verdad que no me estuve a stackoverflow últimamente y recién puedo ver este enorme aporte, avanzando con mi experiencia como programador ya pude entender mejor las facilidades que trae el patrón de diseño y cuando usarlo, pero tus palabras son excelentes, sobre todo para la gente que está arrancando y quizás se tope con las mismas dudas.

Answer (score 4):

Una entidad es un objeto que mapea una tabla en un modelo de base de datos relacional, esta entidad tiene solamente propiedades que representan a las columnas de la tabla que está mapeando. En otras palabras una entidad mapea una estructura de datos(tabla) del modelo de base de datos relacional a un modelo orientado a objetos, donde las tablas se representan como clases y cada fila o tupla de esa tabla sería un objeto en el mundo de la programación orientada a objetos. Las clases de entidad tienen estrictamente la misma cantidad de propiedades que posee la tabla que está mapeando, y no gestionan lógica, es decir no tienen métodos(funciones o procedimientos), solamente propiedades.

Ahora bien el **patrón DTO** permite crear estructuras independientes a nuestro modelo de datos e igual que las clases de entidad solamente tienen propiedades, no tienen nada de lógica.

Ahora bien supongamos que tenemos las **clases de entidad Autor** y **Libro**, donde la relación pudiera establecerse diciendo que un autor ha escrito muchos libros, pero un libro ha sido escrito solamente por un autor, es decir tenemos una relación de uno a muchos, donde el extremo uno sería el autor y el mucho los libros.

La estructura de la **clase entidad Autor** pudiera ser:

```
class Autor
{
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
   public string Pais{ get; set; }
   public int Edad{ get; set; }
   public List<Libro> Libros { get; set; }
}
```

Un autor tiene un nombre, un país, una edad y la lista de libros que ha escrito.

La estructura de la **clase entidad Libro** pudiera ser:

```
class Libro
{
   public string Titulo{ get; set; }
   public string ISBN{ get; set; }
   public string Genero{ get; set; }
   public Autor AutorLibro{ get; set; }
}
```

Un libro tiene un título, un ISBN(es el número de identificación del libro), género(policiaco, aventuras, etc.) y que autor lo escribió.

Y supón que queremos hacer un método que nos devuelva solamente, los títulos de los libros cuyo género es aventura y el nombre del autor , es decir esa supuesta consulta solamente nos devolvería una lista de objetos, donde cada objeto tendría datos de las dos clases de entidad, es decir se combinarían datos de ambas clases y se devolverían como propiedades de un solo objeto, de la **clase entidad Libro** solamente obtendremos el título y de la **clase de entidad Autor** solamente el nombre del autor.

Entonces cuál sería el tipo de datos para los objetos que se devolverían en esa consulta. Puede ser de tipo **Libro** o de tipo **Autor**?

Como verás no puede ser de ninguno de esos tipos pues **Libro** tiene **4 propiedades** y **Autor** también tiene **4 propiedades** y nuestra consulta devolverá un objeto que tiene **2 propiedades** de tipo **string**(**NombreAutor** y **Titulo**).

Entonces como no puede ser del tipo de ninguna de las clases de entidad que tenemos, pues tenemos que crear una nueva clase con esta estructura de dos propiedades de tipo **string**, esto es el **patrón DTO**. La nueva clase bien podría ser:

```
class LibroAventura
{
   public string NombreAutor { get; set; }
   public string Titulo{ get; set; }
}
```

Puedes también ver esta respuesta que trata también el tema de las **clases DTO** para que tengas una idea mejor del concepto y porque aplicarlo:

[Pasar una consulta linq C# de un botón a un clase para ejecutarla y llenar una grilla en un formulario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/456092/pasar-una-consulta-linq-c-de-un-bot%c3%b3n-a-un-clase-para-ejecutarla-y-llenar-una-g/456104#456104)

Comment: Te agradezco la respuesta. En principio me queda claro que a la hora de mostrar la información o los datos usamos las clases DTO.
Ahora siguiendo tu ejemplo: 
En caso en que estuvieramos haciendo un API REST, donde para probar la aplicación tengamos que insertar un nuevo autor que sería correcto usar un modelo entidad? o sería más apropiado usar una clase DTO? porque?

Comment: Si vas a insertar un autor a la base de datos, creas un objeto entidad de tipo autor, ya que este modela a la tabla de Autor en la bd, los DTO son más bien transformaciones de esas clases de entidad, una clase entidad puede tener diferentes clases DTO

Comment: Las clases de entidad son las que persisten en la base de datos, son como las tablas, los DTO digamos que se usan  para crear nuevas representaciones de esos datos que no tienen la misma estructura que las clases de entidad

Comment: Yo podría por ejemplo querer obtener solamente el nombre del autor o el nombre y la edad, como ves son nuevos objetos que tienen una estructura diferente de las clases entidad

Comment: La clases de entidad son el equivalente a las tablas de la bd

Comment: Bien, por lo que entiendo de tu explicación queda claro que el DTO es para mostrar la información existente proveniente de la base de datos/plantilla/etc (que maneje el sistema), y para cargar elementos en la base de datos se pueden usar los modelos de entidad ya que estos representan fielmente la tabla que se encuentre en la base de datos en cuestión.

Comment: Ahora lo que no entiendo es porque cuando veo el código de distintos sitemas los modelos de entidad y los modelos DTO tienen exactamente las mismas propiedades, y a la hora de dar de alta un registro en la base de datos,  tienen que pasar por un ObjectMapper (en java) para transformar o mapear de un clase a otra claseDTO, cuando para crear un registro deberían poder simplemente usar la clase entidad y listo.

Comment: Porque las clases de entidad no son serializables y las DTO si lo son, serializable quiere decir que por ejemplo los atributos de esa clase con sus valores pueden guardarse en determinado formato, quizá json

Comment: Y descerializar es el proceso inverso es decir, coger ese fichero que tiene datos de una clase previamente serializadosen algún formato(json) y guardarlos en un objeto

Comment: Cuando queremos serializar un objeto entidad completo, al este no ser serializable debemos mapearlo a un DTO que si lo es para que pueda ser guardado en determinado formato

Comment: Y cuando queremos descerializar debemos cargar esos datos en DTO y de ahí mapearlos a la clase entidad para su inserción a la base de datos

Comment: Ahora lo que te quedaría es investigar sobre la serializacion de objetos y sus aplicaciones, espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: SI, te agradezco las respuestas. Ahora investigo más sobre la serialización! Muchisimas gracias!